# How to parse xml in sql server to process NULL value in DateTime DataType

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql

I have created a sample query in sql server to parse data from xml and to display it right now.
Although I will be inserting this data in my table but before that I am facing a simple problem.

I want to insert NULL in datetime field `ADDED_DATE="NULL"` as shown in xml given below. But when I executes this query. It gives me error

**Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.**

What mistake am i doing. Please highlight my mistake.

```
declare @xml varchar(1000)
set @xml= '
<ROOT>
    <TX_MAP FK_GUEST_ID="1"  FK_CATEGORY_ID="2" ATTRIBUTE="Test" DESCRIPTION="TestDesc" IS_ACTIVE="1" ADDED_BY="NULL" ADDED_DATE="NULL" MODIFIED_BY="NULL" MODIFIED_DATE="NULL"></TX_MAP>
    <TX_MAP FK_GUEST_ID="2"  FK_CATEGORY_ID="1" ATTRIBUTE="Test2" DESCRIPTION="TestDesc2" IS_ACTIVE="1" ADDED_BY="NULL" ADDED_DATE="NULL" MODIFIED_BY="NULL" MODIFIED_DATE="NULL"></TX_MAP>
</ROOT> '

declare @handle int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @xml

select * from OPENXML(@handle,'/ROOT/TX_MAP',1)
with 
    (
    FK_GUEST_ID INT
    ,FK_CATEGORY_ID VARCHAR(10)
    ,ATTRIBUTE VARCHAR(100)
    ,[DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(100)
    ,IS_ACTIVE VARCHAR(10)
    ,ADDED_BY VARCHAR(100)
    ,ADDED_DATE DATETIME NULL
    ,MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(100)
    ,MODIFIED_DATE DATETIME NULL
    )
```

I am using Sql Server 2005.

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server 2005, why not use the "XML" data type?

Comment: @John: I have already created table, where i will be inserting this data. I am trying to avoid running Transaction at front end. That's why. Here I just provided sample query of select else I will be doing it for insert

Comment: That still doesn't say why you don't use the XML datatype. How hard would it be to change the data type of the column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After googling an hour, I got answer to my question and would like to share with you all so that for future users it become easy.

```
declare @xml varchar(1000)
set @xml= '
<ROOT>
    <TX_MAP FK_GUEST_ID="1"  FK_CATEGORY_ID="2" ATTRIBUTE="Test" DESCRIPTION="TestDesc" IS_ACTIVE="1" ADDED_BY="NULL" ADDED_DATE="12/3/2010" MODIFIED_BY="NULL" MODIFIED_DATE="12/3/2010"></TX_MAP>
    <TX_MAP FK_GUEST_ID="2"  FK_CATEGORY_ID="1" ATTRIBUTE="Test2" DESCRIPTION="TestDesc2" IS_ACTIVE="1" ></TX_MAP>
</ROOT> '

declare @handle int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @xml

select * from OPENXML(@handle,'/ROOT/TX_MAP',1)
with 
    (
    FK_GUEST_ID INT
    ,FK_CATEGORY_ID VARCHAR(10)
    ,ATTRIBUTE VARCHAR(100)
    ,[DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(100)
    ,IS_ACTIVE VARCHAR(10)
    ,ADDED_BY VARCHAR(100)
    ,ADDED_DATE DATETIME
    ,MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(100)
    ,MODIFIED_DATE DATETIME 
    )
```

> **What you need to do is just to omit
>   those attributes that will result into
>   NULL value**.

Answer (score 0):

An XML **element** can be set to `null` like:

```
<ADDED_DATE xsi:nil="true"/>
```

I can't find a way to set an **attribute** to `null` though. Perhaps the only way is to omit it?

Comment: If he changes that attribute to an element, I think it would work even without nil, just <ADDED_DATE>NULL</ADDED_DATE>

Comment: using elements in place of attributes will make it look longer that's why i was trying to avoid. But If i found no alternative then this will be my last choice.