# T-SQL using null value in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which has an XML input parameter. I would like to use null value in XML, but when I try to select using OpenXML, I get a conversion error.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 22
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Migracio') IS NOT NULL)
DROP TABLE #Migracio
CREATE TABLE #Migracio
(
    Fee DECIMAL(16, 4) NULL,
    Percentage DECIMAL(6, 3)
)

    DECLARE @XML XML =
<Elelments xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Elelment>
   <Fee xsi:nil="true"/>
   <Percentage>50</Percentage>
 </Elelment>
</Elelments>

DECLARE @h INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUT, @XML

INSERT INTO [#Migracio] (Fee, Percentage)
 SELECT Fee, Percentage  FROM OPENXML(@h, '/Elelments/Elelment', 6)
 WITH(Fee DECIMAL(16, 4), Percentage DECIMAL(6, 3))

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @h

SELECT * FROM #Migracio
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please post the code in plain text instead of an image.

Comment: I don't know why but enter code function is not working properly for me.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM OPENXML`, together with the stored procedure to open and to remove an XML is outdated and should not be used any more... Rather use the [native XML-methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017) provide by the XML data type.

This `NULL` marker with `xsi:nil` is not really needed. A missing element is taken as a `NULL` value implicitly. If the **existance** of an element is forced by a schema or any kind of rule, this can be used to distinguish between an empty string or a `NULL`. Check this out:

```
DECLARE @XML XML =
'<Elelments xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- your example -->
  <Elelment>
    <Fee xsi:nil="true" />
    <Percentage>50</Percentage>
  </Elelment>

  <!-- both values are set -->
  <Elelment>
    <Fee>100</Fee>
    <Percentage>50</Percentage>
  </Elelment>

  <!-- Fee is missing -->
  <Elelment>
    <Percentage>50</Percentage>
  </Elelment>
</Elelments>';
```

--This will bring back the result you want - without any bothering about `NULL` values

```
SELECT e.value('(Fee/text())[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS Fee
      ,e.value('(Percentage/text())[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS Percentage
FROM @XML.nodes('/Elelments/Elelment') A(e);
```

--So what is the difference? This will return all `<Elelment>` nodes where there is a `<Fee>` node. You get two nodes back. The missing `<Elelment>` is not found.

```
SELECT @XML.query('Elelments/Elelment[Fee]');
```

--with this you can find all `<Fee>` with an explicit value of `xsi:nil="true"`

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT @XML.query('Elelments/Elelment[Fee/@xsi:nil="true"]');
```

Btw: Do you really name this `<Elelment>`? The second "L" is somehow disturbing me...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could Google the answer:

[How to parse xml in sql server to process NULL value in DateTime DataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831927/how-to-parse-xml-in-sql-server-to-process-null-value-in-datetime-datatype)

"What you need to do is just to omit those attributes that will result into NULL value."

Could it be the only way?